# Run macro differently if it has been ran within 2 seconds

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a macro for a shortcut that will merge across, then if the keyboard shortcut is triggered again in quick succession, will merge the entire selection.

The problem I'm running into, is that it appears the same sub cannot be called while it is still running. Is there a way to create a function/sub that can be called while it is still running, or maybe another way around this?

```
Sub MergeAcross()
Selection.Merge (Not MergeAll)
If MergeAll Then
    MergeAll = False
Else
    MergeAll = True
    Dim NowTick As Long
    Dim EndTick As Long
    EndTick = GetTickCount + (2000)
    Do
        NowTick = GetTickCount
        DoEvents
    Loop Until NowTick >= EndTick
    MergeAll = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any reason to be staying stuck in that function for a whole 2 seconds? Have you considered the scope of the `EndTick` variable? Perhaps your problem will go away if you dont stay in that function for so long? ;)

Comment: Dont use thr Do Loop timer. Create a `Static` variable to hold the time the sub is run.  Compare the current time to the static to select which option to run

Comment: Ahh.. of course. That should work, thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub MergeAcross()
    Static lastCallTime As Single
    Selection.Merge (Timer - lastCallTime > 2)
    lastCallTime = Timer
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. For future users, I have changed the timer to .15 and this seems to be an appropriate time.